# SQl Trigger, Limit value from inserted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've got 2 tables :

Table1 : [DocNo],[Numerik],[[MaTune]

Table2 : [DocNo],[RowNo],[Numerik],[MaTune],[DateData]

I would like to create a trigger on Table2:

Each value add into table2, the values [Numerik] and [MaTune] should be reported into table1 where the [DocNo] is similar.

But I found an error if I add a second values with the same doc number. After exam, I found why, when I asked for update date/time, it is reported for each document with the same DocNo and RowNo.

How can I have only the value modify into my trigger?

Here is my code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_MAJ] 
   ON  [dbo].[Table2]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Déclaration des variables
    DECLARE @DocNo INT
    DECLARE @RowNo SMALLINT
    DECLARE @Numerik INT
    DECLARE @MaTune DECIMAL(15,2)
    DECLARE @DocNo_TheCat INT



   --Attribution des variables
    SELECT @DocNo = DocNo, @RowNo=RowNo, @Numerik = Numerik, @MaTune = Matune FROM inserted

   --Mise à jour de la date et l'heure dans Table2
    UPDATE Table2 SET Datedata= GETDATE() WHERE RowNo=@RowNo AND DocNo=@DocNo



   IF (SELECT MaTune from Table1 where DocNo=@DocNo) IS NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Table1 SET MaTune = @MaTune, Numerik = @Numerik where DocNo=@DocNo
    END

    IF (SELECT MaTune from Table1 where DocNo=@DocNo) IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN

            --On attribue les nouvelles variables
            SELECT @DocNo_TheCat = DocNo, @RowNo=RowNo, @Numerik = Numerik, @MaTune = Matune FROM TheIxTable178 where DocNo=@DocNo  and RowNo=@RowNo and datedata = (select TOP 1 MAX(datedata) from Table2)

            UPDATE Table1 SET MaTune = @MaTune, Numerik = @Numerik where DocNo=@DocNo_TheCat
    END





END
```

Comment: `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows. As such, assignments like `SELECT @DocNo = ... FROM inserted` are broken.

Comment: HOw can i limiy the data from inserted with only the one modify ?

Answer (score 0):

when table2 primary key (OK) is in inserted table it means those records are modified (inserted or updated), 
so try to use following code :

```
..... WHERE table2PK in (Select table2PK from inserted)
```

you need to use set operations,

```
UPDATE t1 SET MaTune = mat
FROM inserted i 
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON i.docNO = t2.docno -- or whatever join conditions you assume that is OK!
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.docNo = i.docno
```

Comment: In fact, if something new is inserted into table2, table1 get automatically the value DocNo, the other columns are set to NULL. Could you tell me where to use : WHERE table2PK in (Select table2PK from inserted)

Comment: in the trigger for table2 when you want to update rows in any other tables you can join the target table with inserted table or use WHERE clause to filter the unaffected rows...